# update depending on item within document mongodb pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

suppose that i have a mongodb collection with dictionary objects like such:

```
{
    'value1' : 4 , 
    'value2' : 0  
}
```

and i want to update each dictionary object in the database such that `value2 = value1 / 2`, is there a simple way to do it?

the simple way to do doesnt seem to work because you cannot reference to the `value1` value:

```
some_db.update(  {} , { 'value2' : 'this.value1'/2 } ) # wont work, right?
```

the other way would be to perform batch jobs, pulling in data batch by batch on my own computer such that i can retreive the value of `a` to then update the value of `b`. i would rather have the server perform this opertion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not have functionality for this. You will have to do this in a batch job. If you do so, I would suggest that you make that you sleep a little between each update as to allow the server to perform normally for the application as well. Otherwise you might end up read/write starving the database. Of course, that's only really necessary if you have loads of (millions of) records really.

Comment: would you know if such functionality is planned? it seems like a missing functionality for a db (though im no db guy).

if you want to respec the db for a new norm you are forced to pull a lot of data now it seems, which sounds like a lot of extra computing power thats needed.

Comment: No, sorry. It is being tracked at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1765 though.

Answer (score -1):

hey just do something like this in pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
cursor_object = MongoClient()[your_db][your_collection]
for object in cursor_object.find():
  id = object['_id']
  val1 = object['value1']
  update = val1/2
  cursor_object.update({"_id":id},{"$set":{"value2":update}})
```

Comment: This does not work. You can not use the value of a different column in a set.